# Stepping Through a Progress Bar with For Each Loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach, progress-bar

I have a `ProgressBar` named `ProgressBar1`.  I need it to show the progress of a `For Each` loop.  It steps through fine but at the very end I get this error "`Additional information: Value of '102' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.`"   No matter what I do I can't get the final `ProgressBar1.Value` to match the `ProgressBar1.Value`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Shared tickerArray() As String = {"GOOG", "V", "AAPL", "BBBY", "AMZN", "DISCA"}

ProgressBar1.Maximum = (100 / tickerArray.Length) * tickerArray.Length
ProgressBar1.Show()

For Each tickerValue In tickerArray
    Historical_Stock_Prices.addBulk_Historical_Stock_Prices(tickerValue, tblName)
    ProgressBar1.Value += (100 / tickerArray.Length)
Next tickerValue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you set the Maximum value to the length of your array?

```
ProgressBar1.Maximum = tickerArray.Length
```

Now in the loop you could increment the current value by 1

```
ProgressBar1.Value += 1
```

Comment: Such a simple answer!  I was definitely trying to out-think the room on that one.  Thanks!